# Show $\mathbb{E}(X \mid Y,Z) = \mathbb{E}(X \mid Y)$ if $Z$ is independent of $X$ and $Y$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

> Let $X,Y,Z$ be random variables, $X$ integrable, $Z$ independent of $X$ and $Y$. Then we have $E[X\mid Y,Z]=E[X\mid Y]$. Why is only assuming $Z$ independent of $Y$ not enough.

I was able to verify this for random variables that have a joint density, but I have no idea how to verify this one. I tried using the tower property to no avail. I only want a hint to get started, no full solution.

Comment: Hint: You want to show that $E(E(X|Y)u(Y,Z))=E(Xu(Y,Z))$ for every (bounded measurable) function $u$. Can you show that for a whole class of functions $u$ this identity indeed holds?

Comment: I have the weaker definition of conditional expectation: $E[X\chi_A]=E[E[X|Y]\chi_A]$ for every $A$ in $\sigma(Y)$. I see how showing your stronger version implies the weaker one, My first instinct is using measure-theoretic induction, but I'm stuck in the technical details.

Comment: Right. Then my advice would be to reread my first comment *much more carefully*.

Comment: A standard machinery in measure theory is the [*monotone class theorem*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_class_theorem). The rough idea is that you can first show the claim for indicator functions, then for simple functions, and then for any bounded measurable functions by approximation argument.

Comment: @sos440: This is what I mean by measure-theoretic induction.

Comment: @fstl So where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @saz I was able to solve it. I was not using the fact that it is enough to show it on a intersection-stable generator of $\sigma(Y,Z)$, which your answer reminded me of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. The $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(Y,Z)$ is generated by sets of the form $$\{Y \in A\} \cap \{Z \in B\}$$ for Borel sets $A,B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.
2. By step 1 and the definition of conditional expectation, it suffices to show that $$\int_{\{Y \in A\} \cap \{Z \in B\}} \mathbb{E}(X \mid Y) \, d\mathbb{P} = \int_{\{Y \in A\} \cap \{Z \in B\}} X \, d\mathbb{P} \tag{1} $$ for all $A,B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.
3. Use the given assumption on the independence and the equality $$\int_{\{Y \in B\}} \mathbb{E}(X \mid Y) \, d\mathbb{P} = \int_{\{Y \in B\}} X \, d\mathbb{P}$$ to prove $(1)$.